# Opening textfile in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, text-files

The structure of the data file looks like this:

```
  2.0  0    3    9.15400
      5.40189    0.77828    0.66432
      0.44219    0.00000
  2.0  0    1    9.15400
      0.00000
  2.0  0    6    9.15400
      7.38451    3.99120    2.23459    1.49781    0.77828    0.00000
  2.0  0    3    9.15400
      2.09559    0.77828    0.00000
  2.0  0    3    9.15400
      2.09559    0.77828    0.65828
      0.58990    0.00000
```

and so on

I want to create a data frame that should look like this:

```
9.15400    5.40189    0.77828    0.66432    0.44219    0.00000
9.15400    0.00000
9.15400    7.38451    3.99120    2.23459    1.49781    0.77828    0.000
9.15400    2.09559    0.77828    0.00000
9.15400    2.09559    0.77828    0.65828    0.58990    0.00000
```

Can someone please help me how I can get started with this?

Comment: What if you just read the entire file then filter in pandas?

Comment: Or if you really wanted to, maybe a loop with read_csv/excel with the skipline parameter but that's only the beginning.. It would be a very slow and ugly solution..

Comment: Your latest edit now has `9.15400` within the expected output, although this value is on the line that starts with `2.0`, so would not be included if you "only read lines which do not begin with 2.0". Should  `9.15400` be on a separate line?

Comment: I understand. I would have preferred to include 9.15400 as well from the previous line and then discard all other values and put them in the data frame if possible but if it can not be done then it can be added later manually as it is a constant. I understand it is a bit too complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why doesn't the 0th row of your desired dataframe include `0.66432`?

It's unclear how the table is structured. If it is as unstructured as is shown in your question, try this:

Input:

```
  2.0  0    3    9.15400
      5.40189    0.77828    0.66432
      0.44219    0.00000
  2.0  0    1    9.15400
      0.00000
  2.0  0    6    9.15400
      7.38451    3.99120    2.23459    1.49781    0.77828    0.00000
  2.0  0    3    9.15400
      2.09559    0.77828    0.00000
  2.0  0    3    9.15400
      2.09559    0.77828    0.65828
      0.58990    0.00000
```

```py
filename = r"C:\Users\Bobson Dugnutt\Desktop\table2.txt"

# This returns a dataframe with a single column
df = pd.read_table(filename, header=None)

# Split the bad-boy at every double space
df = df[0].str.split("  ", expand=True)

new_rows = []
values = []

for row in df.itertuples():
    # row[2] is the column which is either 2.0 or blank ("")
    if row[2]:
        if values:
            new_rows.append(values)
            values = []
        
        # row[7] is the column with a value like 9.15400
        values.append(row[7])
    else:
        # Add all non-blank values starting from the the 4th column.
        # The 4th column is the first column meaningful values are 
        # found for these rows
        values.extend(value for value in row[4:] if value)
    
new_rows.append(values)

# fillna("") so make the NaN values blank
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_rows).fillna("")
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
        0       1       2       3       4       5       6
0 9.15400 5.40189 0.77828 0.66432 0.44219 0.00000        
1 9.15400 0.00000                                        
2 9.15400 7.38451 3.99120 2.23459 1.49781 0.77828 0.00000
3 9.15400 2.09559 0.77828 0.00000                        
4 9.15400 2.09559 0.77828 0.65828 0.58990 0.00000
```

Or if each column is fixed width, and is just not displayed correctly in your question, try this:

Input:

```
  2.0  0    3    9.15400
                 5.40189    0.77828    0.66432
                 0.44219    0.00000
  2.0  0    1    9.15400
                 0.00000
  2.0  0    6    9.15400
                 7.38451    3.99120    2.23459    1.49781    0.77828    0.00000
  2.0  0    3    9.15400
                 2.09559    0.77828    0.00000
  2.0  0    3    9.15400
                 2.09559    0.77828    0.65828
                 0.58990    0.00000
```

```py
import pandas as pd

# Make the floats the same width of your desired output
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.5f}'.format

filename = r"C:\Users\Bobson Dugnutt\Desktop\table.txt"

df = pd.read_fwf(filename, header=None).fillna("")

new_rows = []
values = []

for row in df.itertuples():
    # row[1] is the column which is either 2.0 or blank ("")
    if row[1] != "":
        if values:
            new_rows.append(values)
            values = []
        
        # row[4] is the column with a value like 9.15400
        values.append(row[4])
    else:
        # Add all non-blank values starting from the same column as above
        values.extend(value for value in row[4:] if value != "")

new_rows.append(values)

# fillna("") so make the NaN values blank
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_rows).astype(float).fillna("")

print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
        0       1       2       3       4       5       6
0 9.15400 5.40189 0.77828 0.66432 0.44219 0.00000        
1 9.15400 0.00000                                        
2 9.15400 7.38451 3.99120 2.23459 1.49781 0.77828 0.00000
3 9.15400 2.09559 0.77828 0.00000                        
4 9.15400 2.09559 0.77828 0.65828 0.58990 0.00000
```

In both cases all you have to do is iterate over each row, check if one of the first columns is not blank (i.e. is `2.0`), and if it is, then get all the other meaningful values in the next rows until you come across another similar row. The specific index differs depending on how the table was originally parsed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I am trying to use the second method as the first one does not give me the correct output. Here is the file: https://www.swisstransfer.com/d/3c263cbf-ab6d-4ceb-af8f-62634a9c92e7 . For the second method I am using new_df = new_df.astype(float) trying to convert values to float so that I can later manipulate them but this gives an error: could not convert string to float: ''. Can you please tell me how it can be fixed?

Comment: No problemo. I have just updated my answer. I also just realised my 2 codeblocks were mixed up. To avoid that error, either call `astype(float)` before `fillna("")` (like in my updated answer), or pass in "ignore" as the errors argument: `astype(float, errors="ignore")`. I tried with the file you provided, and it all seems to work.

Comment: Thank you very much. Turns out new_df[column index] = pd.to_numeric(new_df[column index], errors='coerce') does the trick as well.